# reproducir videos en bucle en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, bucles, video

necesito hacer una app en windows form que reproduzca unos 6 videos en bucle es deecir, al terminar uno inmediatamente se reproduza el otro y asi sin fin. alguna idea de como hacerlo?
tengo un array que dentro tiene lis links de los videos

---

ahhh, se me olvido comentar que los videos deben de empezar a reproducirse sin ningun boton osea solos en cuanto el form se ejecute

Comment: Bienvenido @Lexi a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Podrias evaluar hacer uso de `Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback` como reproductor

[[C# Winforms] Create your own Video Player (DirectX)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlITlht0E08)

Puedes detectar cuando temrina la reproduccion ya que tienes el evento `Ending`

[c# using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback how to play next video after one is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549084/c-sharp-using-microsoft-directx-audiovideoplayback-how-to-play-next-video-after)

```
public void btnStart_Click()
{
    video = new Video("ruta archivo video");
    video.Owner = viewport;
    video.Play();

    video.Ending +=new EventHandler(Video_Ending);
}

private void Video_Ending(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    video = new Video("ruta del siguiente video");
    video.Owner = viewport;
    video.Play();
}
```

Esta claro que el siguiente video sera el que tomes de la lista que quieres reproducir

Answer (score -2):

bloquea la aplicación, al definir la instancia del objeto Video video=new Video("x.yyy")

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/).